# grunt hang on Running "delta" task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm a newbie to node and grunt, all right, the Front-end technology. The grunt is hang on running "delta" task when i execute `grunt live` command:

```
...    
Running "index:build" (index) task
Running "karma:continuous" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9018/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket suzSULuEb4R90dkkuH9_ with id 66784053
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: 'Starting Karma'
........................
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 24 of 24 SUCCESS (0.095 secs / 0.089 secs)

Running "connect:dev" (connect) task
Started connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "delta" task
Waiting...
```

As shown in the list, `localhost:9000` doesnot work in web server, how to solve this problem ?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "author": "Mathieu Lemay",
  "name": "opendaylight-dlux",
  "description": "openDayLight User eXperience",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "homepage": "http://opendaylight.org",
  "license": "EPL-1.0",
  "bugs": "https://bugs.opendaylight.org/",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/dlux.git"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.22",
    "bower": "~1.3.12",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.2.0",
    "connect-modrewrite": "~0.5.4",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.6",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-bump": "0.0.13",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-coffeelint": "0.0.8",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.8.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-conventional-changelog": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-html2js": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-recess": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-replace": "~0.7.8",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.11",
    "jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.37",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.6",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "recess": "^1.1.9",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.19",
    "ycssmin": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

And here comes my Gruntfile.js, it's a bit complicate:

```
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')();
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

  /**
   * Load required Grunt tasks. These are installed based on the versions listed
   * in `package.json` when you do `npm install` in this directory.
   */
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-conventional-changelog');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bump');
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-recess');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html2js');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace');

  /**
   * Load in our build configuration file.
   */
  var userConfig = require( './build.config.js' );

  var envConfig = {

      replace: {
          development: {
              options: {
                  patterns: [
                      {
                          json: grunt.file.readJSON('./config/development.json')
                      }
                  ]
              },
              files: [
                  {
                      expand: true,
                      flatten: true,
                      src: ['./config/env.module.js'],
                      dest: 'src/common/config/'
                  }
              ]
          },
          production: {
              options: {
                  patterns: [
                      {
                          json: grunt.file.readJSON('./config/production.json')
                      }
                  ]
              },
              files: [
                  {
                      expand: true,
                      flatten: true,
                      src: ['./config/env.module.js'],
                      dest: 'src/common/config/'
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }

  /**
   * This is the configuration object Grunt uses to give each plugin its
   * instructions.
   */
  var taskConfig = {
    /**
     * We read in our `package.json` file so we can access the package name and
     * version. It's already there, so we don't repeat ourselves here.
     */
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

    /**
     * The banner is the comment that is placed at the top of our compiled
     * source files. It is first processed as a Grunt template, where the `<%=`
     * pairs are evaluated based on this very configuration object.
     */
    meta: {
      banner:
        '/**\n' +
        ' * <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
        ' * <%= pkg.homepage %>\n' +
        ' *\n' +
        ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>\n' +
        ' * Licensed <%= pkg.licenses.type %> <<%= pkg.licenses.url %>>\n' +
        ' */\n'
    },

    /**
     * Creates a changelog on a new version.
     */
    changelog: {
      options: {
        dest: 'CHANGELOG.md',
        template: 'changelog.tpl'
      }
    },

    /**
     * Increments the version number, etc.
     */
    bump: {
      options: {
        files: [
          "package.json",
          "bower.json"
        ],
        commit: false,
        commitMessage: 'chore(release): v%VERSION%',
        commitFiles: [
          "package.json",
          "client/bower.json"
        ],
        createTag: false,
        tagName: 'v%VERSION%',
        tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%',
        push: false,
        pushTo: 'origin'
      }
    },

    /**
     * The directories to delete when `grunt clean` is executed.
     */
    clean: [
      '<%= build_dir %>',
      '<%= compile_dir %>'
    ],

    /**
     * The `copy` task just copies files from A to B. We use it here to copy
     * our project assets (images, fonts, etc.) and javascripts into
     * `build_dir`, and then to copy the assets to `compile_dir`.
     */
    copy: {
      build_app_assets: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '**' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/assets/',
            cwd: 'src/assets',
            expand: true
          }
       ]
      },
      build_vendor_assets: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= vendor_files.assets %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/assets/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true
          }
       ]
      },
      build_appjs: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= app_files.js %>', '<%= app_files.css %>', '<%= app_files.lang %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      copy_template: {
        files: [
          {
            src: ['<%= app_files.templates %>'],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      build_vendorjs: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= vendor_files.js %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      build_appimages: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= app_files.images %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      build_vendorimages: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= vendor_files.images %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      build_vendorcss: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= vendor_files.css %>' ],
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>',
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },
      compile_assets: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '**' ],
            dest: '<%= compile_dir %>/assets',
            cwd: '<%= build_dir %>/assets',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      },

      compile_font: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '**' ],
            dest: '<%= compile_dir %>/font',
            cwd: '<%= build_dir %>/font',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    /**
     * `grunt concat` concatenates multiple source files into a single file.
     */
    concat: {
      /**
       * The `build_css` target concatenates compiled CSS and vendor CSS
       * together.
       */
      build_css: {
        src: [
          '<%= vendor_files.css %>',
          '<%= build_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.css'
        ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.css'
      },
      /**
       * The `compile_js` target is the concatenation of our application source
       * code and all specified vendor source code into a single file.
       */
      compile_js: {
        options: {
          banner: '<%= meta.banner %>'
        },
        src: [
          '<%= vendor_files.js %>',
          'module.prefix',
          '<%= build_dir %>/src/**/*.js',
          '<%= html2js.common.dest %>',
          '<%= html2js.app.dest %>',
          'module.suffix'
        ],
        dest: '<%= compile_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.js'
      }
    },

    /**
     * `ng-min` annotates the sources before minifying. That is, it allows us
     * to code without the array syntax.
     */
    ngAnnotate: {
      options: {
        singleQuotes:true
      },
      app: {
        files: [
          {
            src: [ '<%= app_files.js %>' ],
            cwd: '<%= build_dir %>',
            dest: '<%= build_dir %>',
            expand: true
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    /**
     * Minify the sources!
     */
    uglify: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          banner: '<%= meta.banner %>'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= concat.compile_js.dest %>': '<%= concat.compile_js.dest %>'
        }
      }
    },

      /**
       * `less` less plugin handles the LESS compilation and minification automatically
       * this has been changed to the LESS plugin from recess plugin above because of
       * out of memory issues with the original plugin.
       */

      less: {
          development: {
              options: {
                  paths: ["assets/css"],
                  compress: false,
                  syncImport: true,
                  strictImports: true
              },
              files: {
                  '<%= build_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.css': '<%= app_files.less %>'
                  }
          },
          production: {
              options: {
                  paths: ["assets/css"],
                  compress: true,
                  cleancss: true
              },
              files: {
                  '<%= build_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.css': '<%= app_files.less %>'
              }
          }
      },

    /**
     * `jshint` defines the rules of our linter as well as which files we
     * should check. This file, all javascript sources, and all our unit tests
     * are linted based on the policies listed in `options`. But we can also
     * specify exclusionary patterns by prefixing them with an exclamation
     * point (!); this is useful when code comes from a third party but is
     * nonetheless inside `src/`.
     */
    jshint: {
      src: [
        '<%= app_files.js %>',
        '<%= app_files.app_assets %>',
      ],
      test: [
        '<%= app_files.jsunit %>'
      ],
      gruntfile: [
        'OriginalGruntfile.js'
      ],
      options: {
        curly: true,
        immed: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true
      },
      globals: {}
    },


    /**
     * HTML2JS is a Grunt plugin that takes all of your template files and
     * places them into JavaScript files as strings that are added to
     * AngularJS's template cache. This means that the templates too become
     * part of the initial payload as one JavaScript file. Neat!
     */
    html2js: {
      /**
       * These are the templates from `src/app`.
       */
      app: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/app'
        },
        src: [ '<%= app_files.atpl %>' ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/templates-app.js'
      },

      /**
       * These are the templates from `src/common`.
       */
      common: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/common'
        },
        src: [ '<%= app_files.ctpl %>' ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/templates-common.js'
      }
    },

    /**
     * The Karma configurations.
     */
    karma: {
      options: {
        configFile: '<%= build_dir %>/karma-unit.js'
      },
      unit: {
        runnerPort: 9102,
        background: true,
        port: 9877 // IMPORTANT!
      },
      continuous: {
        singleRun: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
      }
    },

    /**
     * The `index` task compiles the `index.html` file as a Grunt template. CSS
     * and JS files co-exist here but they get split apart later.
     */
    index: {

      /**
       * During development, we don't want to have wait for compilation,
       * concatenation, minification, etc. So to avoid these steps, we simply
       * add all script files directly to the `<head>` of `index.html`. The
       * `src` property contains the list of included files.
       */
      build: {
        dir: '<%= build_dir %>',
        src: [
          '<%= html2js.common.dest %>',
          '<%= html2js.app.dest %>',
          '<%= vendor_files.css %>',
          '<%= build_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.css'
        ]
      },

      /**
       * When it is time to have a completely compiled application, we can
       * alter the above to include only a single JavaScript and a single CSS
       * file. Now we're back!
       */
      compile: {
        dir: '<%= compile_dir %>',
        src: [
          '<%= concat.compile_js.dest %>',
          '<%= concat.build_css.dest %>'
          //'<%= recess.compile.dest %>'
        ]
      }
    },

    /**
     * This task compiles the karma template so that changes to its file array
     * don't have to be managed manually.
     */
    karmaconfig: {
      unit: {
        dir: '<%= build_dir %>',
        src: [
          '<%= vendor_files.js %>',
          '<%= html2js.app.dest %>',
          '<%= html2js.common.dest %>',
          '<%= app_files.js_common %>',
          '<%= app_files.js_app %>',
          '<%= app_files.jsunit %>'
        ]
      }
    },
     connect: {
      livereload: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          hostname: '0.0.0.0',
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              mountFolder(connect, 'build'),
              lrSnippet
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          hostname: '0.0.0.0',
          port: 9000,
          base: 'build'
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: 'bin',
          keepalive: true
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      dev: {
        path: 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/'
      },
      prod: {
        path: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/'
      }
    },
    /**
     * And for rapid development, we have a watch set up that checks to see if
     * any of the files listed below change, and then to execute the listed
     * tasks when they do. This just saves us from having to type "grunt" into
     * the command-line every time we want to see what we're working on; we can
     * instead just leave "grunt watch" running in a background terminal. Set it
     * and forget it, as Ron Popeil used to tell us.
     *
     * But we don't need the same thing to happen for all the files.
     */
    delta: {
      /**
       * By default, we want the Live Reload to work for all tasks; this is
       * overridden in some tasks (like this file) where browser resources are
       * unaffected. It runs by default on port 35729, which your browser
       * plugin should auto-detect.
       */
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },

      /**
       * When the Gruntfile changes, we just want to lint it. In fact, when
       * your Gruntfile changes, it will automatically be reloaded!
       */
      gruntfile: {
        files: 'OriginalGruntfile.js',
        tasks: [ 'jshint:gruntfile' ],
        options: {
          livereload: false
        }
      },

      /**
       * When our JavaScript source files change, we want to run lint them and
       * run our unit tests.
       */
      jssrc: {
        files: [
          '<%= app_files.js %>', '<%= app_files.lang %>'
        ],
        tasks: [ 'jshint:src', 'karma:unit:run', 'copy:build_appjs' ]
      },

      /**
       * When assets are changed, copy them. Note that this will *not* copy new
       * files, so this is probably not very useful.
       */
      assets: {
        files: [
          'src/assets/**/*'
        ],
        tasks: [ 'copy:build_app_assets' ]
      },

      /**
       * When index.html changes, we need to compile it.
       */
      html: {
        files: [ '<%= app_files.html %>' ],
        tasks: [ 'index:build' ]
      },

      /**
       * When our templates change, we only rewrite the template cache.
       */
      tpls: {
        files: [
          '<%= app_files.atpl %>',
          '<%= app_files.ctpl %>'
        ],
        tasks: ['copy:copy_template']/*[ 'html2js' ]*/
      },

      /**
       * When the CSS files change, we need to compile and minify them.
       */
      less: {
        files: [ 'src/**/*.less' ],
        tasks: [ 'less:development' ]
      },

      /**
       * When a JavaScript unit test file changes, we only want to lint it and
       * run the unit tests. We don't want to do any live reloading.
       */
      jsunit: {
        files: [
          '<%= app_files.jsunit %>'
        ],
        tasks: [ 'jshint:test', 'karma:unit:run' ],
        options: {
          livereload: false
        }
      }
    },
    shell : {
      requirejs: {
        command: "node node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o optimize.js"
      }
    }
  };

  grunt.initConfig( grunt.util._.extend( taskConfig, userConfig, envConfig ) );

  /**
   * In order to make it safe to just compile or copy *only* what was changed,
   * we need to ensure we are starting from a clean, fresh build. So we rename
   * the `watch` task to `delta` (that's why the configuration var above is
   * `delta`) and then add a new task called `watch` that does a clean build
   * before watching for changes.
   */
  grunt.renameTask( 'watch', 'delta' );
  grunt.registerTask( 'watch', [ 'build', 'karma:unit', 'delta' ] );

  grunt.registerTask('live', ['build', 'connect:dev', 'delta']);
  /**
   * The default task is to build and compile.
   */
  grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'compile' ] );

  /**
   * The `build` task gets your app ready to run for development and testing.
   */
  grunt.registerTask( 'common', [
      'clean', 'html2js', 'jshint', 'concat:build_css', 'less:development',
      'copy:build_app_assets', 'copy:build_vendor_assets',
      'copy:build_appjs', 'copy:copy_template', 'copy:build_vendorimages', 'copy:build_appimages', 'copy:build_vendorjs', 'copy:build_vendorcss', 'karmaconfig', 'index:build'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask( 'build', ['replace:development', 'common', 'karma:continuous']);

  /**
   * The `compile` task gets your app ready for deployment by concatenating and
   * minifying your code.
   */
  grunt.registerTask( 'compile', ['replace:production', 'common', 'karma:continuous', 'ngAnnotate', 'shell:requirejs']);

  /**
   * A utility function to get all app JavaScript sources.
   */
  function filterForJS ( files ) {
    return files.filter( function ( file ) {
      return file.match( /\.js$/ );
    });
  }

  /**
   * A utility function to get all app CSS sources.
   */
  function filterForCSS ( files ) {
    return files.filter( function ( file ) {
      return file.match( /\.css$/ );
    });
  }

  /**
   * The index.html template includes the stylesheet and javascript sources
   * based on dynamic names calculated in this Gruntfile. This task assembles
   * the list into variables for the template to use and then runs the
   * compilation.
   */
  grunt.registerMultiTask( 'index', 'Process index.html template', function () {
    var dirRE = new RegExp( '^('+grunt.config('build_dir')+'|'+grunt.config('compile_dir')+')\/', 'g' );
    var jsFiles = filterForJS( this.filesSrc ).map( function ( file ) {
      return file.replace( dirRE, '' );
    });
    var cssFiles = filterForCSS( this.filesSrc ).map( function ( file ) {
      return file.replace( dirRE, '' );
    });

    grunt.file.copy('src/index.html', this.data.dir + '/index.html', {
      process: function ( contents, path ) {
        return grunt.template.process( contents, {
          data: {
            scripts: jsFiles,
            styles: cssFiles,
            version: grunt.config( 'pkg.version' )
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * In order to avoid having to specify manually the files needed for karma to
   * run, we use grunt to manage the list for us. The `karma/*` files are
   * compiled as grunt templates for use by Karma. Yay!
   */
  grunt.registerMultiTask( 'karmaconfig', 'Process karma config templates', function () {
    var jsFiles = filterForJS( this.filesSrc );

    grunt.file.copy( 'karma/karma-unit.tpl.js', grunt.config( 'build_dir' ) + '/karma-unit.js', {
      process: function ( contents, path ) {
        return grunt.template.process( contents, {
          data: {
            scripts: jsFiles
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "localhost:9000 doesnot work in web server" ? Did you try pointing your browser to address `http://localhost:9000` ? More, grunt is not hanged: when it prints "Waiting..." it is simply waiting for request...

Comment: @MarcoS Visit this address is no respond in a long time and fail at last

Comment: @MarcoS Really ? so the waiting message means run successfully?

Comment: You should show your Gruntfile...

Comment: @MarcoS added already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Waiting..." usually means the server is up and running...
But I see right now watching your Gruntfile that the message "Started **connect** web server on localhost:9000" you see after `grunt live` means a **connect** web server was started (see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect), and not a '*real*' web server, which you can point your browser to (this is why you don't get any answer from `http://localhost:9000`...).
It looks like to me your Gruntfile is designed to set up a *test* environment, and not a staging environment (which is what I think you do expect...).
How to design a staging environment depends upon you app...
For example, do you use `express` (http://expressjs.com/) or something similar to setup a web framework?
If the answer is yes, you should simply add a task to run `node app.js`; if the answer is 'no', you should specify which web server you are using...

Comment: yes, i can use `curl http://localhost:9000` to visit my web but cannot in browser. I think it's need come plugin in browser, i'll try later. thx~